# How to duplicate a matrix with awk?

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

I have the following 4 x 3 matrix with fields separated by a space.

Input

```
12.34 34.3 2.34
1.23 45.78 79.56
1.45 78.5 23.50
78.45 23.33 45.8
```

How to duplicate this matrix n times, in this case 2 times using `awk` or `sed`?

Desired output

```
12.34 34.3 2.34
1.23 45.78 79.56
1.45 78.5 23.50
78.45 23.33 45.8
12.34 34.3 2.34
1.23 45.78 79.56
1.45 78.5 23.50
78.45 23.33 45.8
```

Thanks for your help.

Tony

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '1' ./infile ./infile

sed -n 'p' ./infile ./infile

cat ./infile ./infile
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to provide some more context; in what form is the original matrix and what would you like to do with it? Other than that, use:

```
$ cat matrix
12.34 34.3 2.34
1.23 45.78 79.56
1.45 78.5 23.50
78.45 23.33 45.8

$ cat matrix matrix 
12.34 34.3 2.34
1.23 45.78 79.56
1.45 78.5 23.50
78.45 23.33 45.8
12.34 34.3 2.34
1.23 45.78 79.56
1.45 78.5 23.50
78.45 23.33 45.8
```

Answer (score 1):

To repeat it N times you can use:

```
perl -ne '{$x.=$_}END{print $x x N}' file
```

In your case replace `N` with `2`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way if the matrix is in a file `matrix.txt` is with `cat`:

```
cat matrix.txt matrix.txt
```

You can achieve essentially the same effect with `sed`:

```
sed 's/^//' matrix.txt matrix.txt
```

There aren't many other ways to do it easily with `sed`.  You can also pull the same stunt with `awk`:

```
awk '{print $0}' matrix.txt matrix.txt
```

There's also a devious shorthand:

```
awk 1 matrix.txt matrix.txt
```

(*Hint*: the default action is `print $0`.)

Using `awk`, you can also arrange to read the file just once:

```
awk '{line[NR] = $0}
     END { for (j = 1; j <= 2; j++) { for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++) print line[i] } }' \
    matrix.txt
```

This is a space-time trade-off; `awk` is internalizing a copy of the file and regurgitating it twice;

Answer (score 1):

```
$ for i in {1..2}; do cat matrix.txt; done
$ sed -n 'H; ${g;s/.*/&&/p}' matrix.txt
```

To duplicate this matrix `10` times, just change `2`(`&&`) to `10`(`&&&&&&&&&&`)

Comment: The sed solution gives you an extra newline at the start of the pattern space (`H` appends a newline then appends the PS to the hold space) `sed -n 'H; ${g;s/.*/&&/;s/.//p}' matrix.txt` fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;:b;p;x;s/^/x/;/x\{2\}/d;x;bb' matrix.txt
```

Where `/x\{2\}/` acts as a counter i.e.  repeat 12 times change to `/x\{12\}/`